# Putting date after after file name

Tags: vba, date, outlook

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk6(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "P:\me\"
Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd")
 For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If InStr(1, objAtt.FileName, "ASDFA", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & " ADFA ADF.pdf"
        ElseIf InStr(1, itm.Subject, "ASDF ADSF ADSF", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & " ASD ASDF ASD.pdf"
        ElseIf InStr(1, objAtt.FileName, "ASDDAAD", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & " ASDF ADF AD.pdf"
        Else
  End If
  Set objAtt = Nothing
 Next
End Sub
```

Changed file names for privacy, but I want to put the date after the file name but I need the .pdf to save the files as pdf's. The files I get are pdf's in the email but for some reason I could only get this to work by appending .pdf at the end of the file name. Is there any way to get this to save as "ASDD ASDAS 2016.05.11.pdf" instead of "2016.05.11 ADSF ASDF.pdf"?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & " ASDF ADF AD" & dateFormat & ".pdf"

Comment: ".pdf" <-- i forgot the dot above!